# How to permute 256 bits in AVX-512

Tags: avx512

I want to know if there is any instruction to shuffle half 256 bits of 512 bits in AVX-512.

I try to ifinish a function that get the low half 256 bits from src1(zmm register) and the low half from src2 to form dst zmm register.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then `vinserti32x8` should do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate 256-bits variables in a 512-bits variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434879/how-to-concatenate-256-bits-variables-in-a-512-bits-variable)